# JWT Auth token works in Homestead but not on production server

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors, token, satellizer

So here is the deal. I have an [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) app with "[satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)" and "[angular-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt)" which communicates with a Laravel5 backend with [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) and [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth). Running this combo works fine in [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead) in combination witg ionic serve. An authentication token is created and stored in localStorage and validates with Laravel. This request looks as followed:

```
[IONIC SERVE] http://192.168.1.54:8100/#/auth
[POST] http://192.168.10.10/api/v1/authenticate?email=[email]&password=[password]  
Returns [the_token]  
[GET] http://192.168.10.10/api/v1/authenticate/user?token=[the_token]  
Returns the user object from Laravel
```

As soon as I change the api url to my live server

```
[POST] http://domaintomyvps.com/api/v1/authenticate?email=[email]&password=[password]  
Returns [the_token]  
[GET] http://domaintomyvps.com/api/v1/authenticate/user?token=[the_token]  
Returns {"error":"token_not_provided"}
```

The authentication works fine and a token got returned. But when sending the get request I get the error "token_not_provided".

Then the strange thing happens. When trying the same request from Chrome Postman the token validates and the user object is returned.

My homestead is running as a Vagrant in a VirtualBox and Nginx in Ubuntu. My production server is Debian with Apache on a VPS. The Laravel installations are identical regarding settings and keys. The database is exactly the same (mysqldump) and works due Postman creates a successful result.

Anyone who can guide me to the right direction or has had the same problem? Do you need any more information regarding setup or code?

Comment: are requests being made cross domain? If so likely a CORS issue

Comment: Yes they are. That's why the package barryvdh/laravel-cors is installed which gives access to the server. The first authentication when posting email and password is working crossdomain. The requests between my local virtualbox and ionic are also CORS and working fine due the CORS package

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem.
Adding the following to my apache .htaccess disable apache to remove auth header from the request. I found this answer in the: [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171727/reading-authorization-header-for-jwt-token-using-laravel-5-cors-and-jwtauth)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: God bless you kind person

Comment: God bless you again